# CSS border-top height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the height of my top border. I have read around that this is not possible in traditional ways. But I am yet to find a workaround for this. I need my border to align at the very top of the page. So what can I do?

HTML

```
<li class="active">Hjem</li>
```

CSS

```
li.active
{
    border-top:3px solid #000;
}
```

** The problem is that with the current code the height of the border, meaning the space between the border and the text is locked. I need to control this.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle or demo?

Comment: _"I have read around that this is not possible in traditional ways. "_ I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7GBE/ You have to show us more code to understand the specific problem

Comment: You haven't stated what the problem is. There's no obvious problem with your code.

Comment: what is the actual problem? you didn't specify..

Comment: The problem is that with the current code the height of the border, meaning the space between the border and the text is locked. I need to control this.

Comment: provide at least an image or a fiddle with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you

Comment: `** The problem is that with the current code the height of the border, meaning the space between the border and the text is locked.`Do you hear something like padding?

Comment: Instead of using a `border-top` use an `::after` or a `::before` pseudo-element. There you can set the height as expected

Answer (score -1):

I had tried out. I dont see any problem with the current code. Created JsFiddle. It worked as expected.

```
li.active
{
    border-top:3px solid #000;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VSnnd/151/)